# Run a PowerShell script on a website with a HTML button

Tags: html, powershell, button, web

I created a *PowerShell* script. It makes a lot of things and creates an HTML-file.
This HTML-file runs on a webserver, the *PowerShell* script is on the same server.

I have the following button in my HTML-file:

```
<button type="button">Run Powershell Script</button>
```

If you click on this button, it should run the *PowerShell* script on the server.

How can I realise that?

Comment: This question can't be answered without providing more information about your application, e. g. which backend technologie are you using?

Comment: The Webserver is a Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS. The website is running on this server (IIS), and the Powershell script is also on this server.

Comment: And which technologie are you using within your *backend*? e. g. ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: I'm using PHP as backend technologie

Comment: I'm not sure if this is help for you: I'm thinking about a webservice that uses powershell for some things too. Due to security concernes (lowest permissions for webserver service account) I will try to achive this by indirect commands: The webserver will throw some data into files in a folder and powershell monitors the folder and files and interpretes all data to derive cmmands from it,  instead of beeing able to be started by the webserver direct.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the problem is, I can't start a Powershell script from my website with HTML. I must use a serverbased technologie (like PHP), but I don't know how I can programming that.

Answer (score -1):

There is no easy way to make this. You would need to build handler solution for this.

You could try to use [Powershell Server](http://www.powershellserver.com/) which have the capacity of running/invoking scripts on a server side. Syntax for HTML documents is not that hard and there's plenty of examples.

Comment: But I don't want a Powershell Server, I want to host a website on a webserver and start the script over a website button